# Simple LinqToSql POCO, is AutoMapping the only option?

Tags: linq-to-sql, automapper, poco

Right now I'm deciding on a `OR/M` for a solution I'm working on. I'm at a crossroads between EF on one hand, and LinqToSql and [**Dapper**](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) (both) on the other hand.

The fact that SO uses L2SQL and Dapper (for performance bottlenecks) draws me to implementing this solution. What initially drew me to EF was the simplicity with which I could implement POCO entities.

I googled for a reasonable while and I couldn't find what I'm looking for. I'd like a clean and simple solution to use LinqToSql with POCO entities. That is, having a repository contract with POCO entities, and not having to manually map these to LinqToSql entities. Can this be achieved easily through the use of [**AutoMapper**](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)?

I figure it shouldn't be an issue, nor take more than a pair of calls to map from POCO to L2SQL and then back (for the return value) to POCO.

Are there any extensions methods I could look into, that would create a default mapper if it was never instantiated?

Are there other solutions to this other than using some kind of mapping tool, like what you do with `CreateObjectSet<T>` in EF?

Comment: AutoMapper is great for mapping view models and dto's. Not so much for trying to keep entire object graphs in sync. You'll lose a lot of automatic stuff and pull out lots of hair trying to replace it.

Comment: What kind of automatic stuff do you mean I'd be losing?

Comment: Well, keeping relations in order, for one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: L2S maintains the relations between the objects for you (as does any ORM). That is one of the things that the Entities do for you. EF with POCOs does it via its own methods, too. Mapping to plain objects loses that.

Comment: So what would you suggest instead?

Comment: I would recommend a hybrid of EF POCO's for most complex stuff, and Dapper for performance-critical things. If performance/scalability will be an issue in some places, mapping back and forth might not be something you want to do alot.